# Maximize the number of isolated nodes in a network

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to know which node(s) should I delete if I want to maximize the number of isolated node in my undirected network?

For instance in the following R script, I would like the result to be H if I delete 1 node and H & U if I delete 2 nodes and so on ...

```
 library(igraph)
 graph <- make_graph( ~ A-B-C-D-A, E-A:B:C:D,
              G-H-I, 
              K-L-M-N-K, O-K:L:M:N,
              P-Q-R-S-P,
                C-I, L-T, O-T, M-S,
              C-P, C-L, I-U-V,V-H,U-H,H-W)
  plot(graph)
```

[image: network example]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to do something like:

1. Compute the k-coreness of each node (just called Graph.coreness in the python bindings, don't know about R).
2. Find the node with k-coreness 2, that connects to the largest number of nodes with k-coreness 1.

## Edit:

Your counter-example was spot on, so I resorted to brute force (which is still linear time in this case).
This is a brute force python implementation that could be optimised (only loop over nodes with k-coreness 1), but it completes in linear time and should be accessible even if you don't know python.

```
import numpy as np
import igraph

def maximise_damage(graph):
    coreness = graph.coreness()

    # find number of leaves for each node
    n = graph.vcount()
    number_of_leaves = np.zeros((n))
    for ii in range(n):
        if coreness[ii] == 1:
            neighbour = graph.neighbors(ii) # list of length 1
            number_of_leaves[neighbour] += 1

    # rank nodes by number of leaves
    order = np.argsort(number_of_leaves)

    # reverse order such that the first element has the most leaves
    order = order[::-1]

    return order, number_of_leaves[order]
```

## EDIT 2:

Just realised this will not work in general for cases where you want to delete more than 1 node at a time. But I think the general approach would still work -- I will think about it some more.

## EDIT 3:

Here we go; still linear. You will need to process the output a little bit though -- some solutions are less than the number of nodes that you want to delete, and then you have to combine them.

```
import numpy as np
import igraph

def maximise_damage(graph, delete=1):
    # get vulnerability
    # nodes are vulnerable if their degree count is lower
    # than the number of nodes that we want to delete
    vulnerability = np.array(graph.degree())

    # create a hash table to keep track of all combinations of nodes to delete
    combinations = dict()

    # loop over vulnerable nodes
    for ii in np.where(vulnerability <= delete)[0]:
        # find neighbours of vulnerable nodes and
        # count the number of vulnerable nodes for that combination
        neighbours = tuple(graph.neighbors(ii))
        if neighbours in combinations:
            combinations[neighbours] += 1
        else:
            combinations[neighbours] = 1

    # determine rank of combinations by number of vulnerable nodes dangling from them
    combinations, counts = combinations.keys(), combinations.values()

    # TODO:
    # some solutions will contain less nodes than the number of nodes that we want to delete;
    # combine these solutions

    return combinations, counts
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand well how to do it for 1 node but how can I use it if I want to delete any number of vertex ?

Comment: Also, if I have 3 nodes (X,Y, Z) link to the A node in the example above, X,Y,Z would have a k-coreness of 1 and A a k-coreness of 3 and I should better delete A rather than any of the k-coreness 2 nodes !

Comment: For instance: graph <- make_graph( ~ A-B-C-D-A, E-A:B:C:D,G-H-I, C-I, I-U-V,V-H,U-H,H-W,A-Z,A-Y,A-X) ; plot(graph,vertex.color=coreness(graph))

Comment: You are right, and I haven't got a solution now. I will think about it. How big is the graph that you will want to use this for?

Comment: Wow ! Thank for all the help. I will test your solution as soon I have a few minutes. The biggest graph I use has ~ 500 nodes so I need to check if brute force is a possibility.

Comment: Lol. Yes, brute force will be fine.

Comment: I did not have much time to work on this pb during last weeks but I implemented in R something similar to your code; I just introduced graph2=delete.vertices(graph,neighbours) in the loop to count the number of isolated nodes. It seems to work for most of kind of network,